# Ubuntu installed in Windows but want to format Windows

Tags: wubi

What will happen to the Ubuntu in this situation?

The Windows is Windows 7.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you have a Wubi install of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

If you did a Wubi install of Ubuntu, Ubuntu is installed inside the Windows partition.

If you wipe that Windows partition (eg, by formatting  it), you will also delete Ubuntu.

Comment: what if the Ubuntu is installed in another partition, not the Windows 7 partition which is in C:/? Will I able to boot the Ubuntu through GRUB?

Comment: What you're describing there sounds like a real install (dual boot). In that case it would be okay to remove Windows but reinstalling Windows would wipe out Grub. [This can be fixed quite easily with a LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).